# add jsp to servlet and maven project

Tags: java, maven, jsp, servlets

I want to add JSP files to servlet project using Maven

Here's my `pom.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>time_table</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>



    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <url>http://localhost:8085/manager/text</url>
                    <server>TomcatServer</server>
                    <path>/time</path>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

How and where should I add JSP files?
and if I have some link to tutorials about this I'm very happy to check

Comment: Have you check this  https://www.codejava.net/coding/java-servlet-and-jsp-hello-world-tutorial-with-eclipse-maven-and-apache-tomcat ?

Comment: yes this tutarial use eclips ide but im using intelij so i cant add jsp pages like that
@Mansi

Comment: what is your project structure?

Comment: https://mkyong.com/maven/how-to-create-a-web-application-project-with-maven/ Might help.